# Restore AES key from MPC

Tags: aes, multiparty-computation

I know there are many AES MPC implementations, but in general, is it possible to restore the raw AES key if we have access to all of the nodes? If we take, for example, VIFF and its "shares". Is it difficult?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the values of all nodes you can always easily recover the plaintext in MPC.

Comment: Indeed, if this were not the case, then you could implement white-box cryptography by implementing all the nodes on a multiparty MPC implementation on the same device...

Comment: I have to tell the whitebox guys they'll love this idea.

Comment: Indeed; it would be a lot simpler than what they're doing now...

Comment: by plaintext you mean AES key?

Comment: @Johndow Doesn't really matter. Whatever was protected by splitting it between the different parties is available if you combine the data from all the parties.